# Add Custom Class in bs-datepicker-container

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am using **"import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker'"** and I want to include custom class in **"bs-datepicker-container"** tag which is marked in provided picture. Is this possible in **ngx-bootstrap** or not. Please let me know.

[Main image for Add Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aUJ2.png)
[Coding Image in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd5kd.png)